# Zero/Nul separator breaks column command

Tags: text-processing, command-line, text-formatting, columns

### Problem

**I want to parse some data structured as lines (`\n` separated) with fields separated by the `NUL` character `\0`.**

Many linux commands handle this separator with options such as `--zero` for `find`, or `-0` for `xargs` or by defining the separator as `\0` for `gawk`.

I didn't manage to understand how to make `column` interpret `NUL` as separator.

### Example

If you generate the following set of data (2 lines with 3 columns, separated by `\0`):

```
echo -e "line1\nline2" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\0"} {print $1"columnA",$1"columnB",$1"columnC"}'
```

You would get the expected following output (`\0` separators won't be displayed but is separating each field):

```
line1columnAline1columnBline1columnC
line2columnAline2columnBline2columnC
```

But when I try to use column to display my column, despite passing `\0`, the output for some reason only display the first column:

```
echo -e "line1\nline2" \ | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\0"; OFS="\0"} {print $1"columnA",$1"columnB",$1"columnC"}' | column -s '\0'
```

```
line1columnA    line2columnA
```

Actually, even without providing the delimiter, column seems to break on the nul character:

```
echo -e "line1\nline2" \ | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\0"; OFS="\0"} {print $1"columnA",$1"columnB",$1"columnC"}' | column
```

```
line1columnA    line2columnA
```

### Question

- **Is there a way to use `\0` as a field/column separator in `column` ?**
- Optional/ bonus question: Why does column behaves like this (I would expect the `\0` to be totally ignored if not managed and the whole line to be printed as a single field) ?
- Optional/ bonus question 2: Some data in these columns will be file paths and I wanted to use `\0` as a best practice. Do you a have better practice to recommand for storing "random strings" in file without having to escape potential conflictual field separator character they may contain?

Comment: You may be able to us `tr` to change them.

Comment: Maybe do what CSV does and use double-quotes to surround fields containing the column separator **and** allow escaping of double-quotes inside double-quotes with either `""` or `\"`.  In fact, why not use CSV?  It's easy to work with, and most languages have decent libraries for parsing and outputting properly-formed CSV.

Comment: Leave FS="\0" as is, and change OFS=" " (white space.) Then change "column -s '\0' to  "column -t".

Comment: @cas, it's a good idea: do you have any recommandation of csv tool for linux? it's for a shell script and ideally the more standard tool already installed would have the favor over better but obscure third library.

Comment: @CinaedSimson: in this example it should work, but rebut if one of your column name gets a space in it, you loose the benefit of nul byte separator and your end result would break

Comment: perl and python, of course.  For tools, there's [csvtool](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv) , [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit), [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and more - these should be available packaged for most distros.   I don't use them much personally, because I find it easier to just write something in perl with `Text::CSV` or `DBD::CSV` when I need to work with CSV files.  If I were to use one regularly, it would probably be `miller`.

Comment: Just insert a simple sed pipe after the echo using sed to replace spaces with underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use \0 as a field/column separator in column ?

No, because both implementations of `column` (that I am aware of), which are [the historical BSD](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/usr.bin/column/column.c?h=stable/13#n299) and the one in [the util-linux package](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/text-utils/column.c#n521), both use the standard C library's string manipulation functions to parse input lines, and those functions work under the assumption that strings are NUL-terminated. In other words, a NUL byte is meant to *always* mark the *end* of *any* string.

> Optional/ bonus question: Why does column behaves like this (I would expect the \0 to be totally ignored if not
> managed and the whole line to be printed as a single field) ?

On top of what I explained above, note that option `-s` expects *literal* characters. [It does not](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/usr.bin/column/column.c?h=stable/13#n105) parse an escape syntax like `\0` (nor `\n` for that matters). This means that [you told `column` to consider either a `\` and a `0` as valid separators](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/text-utils/column.c#n802) for its input.

You can provide escape sequences through the `$''` string syntax if you are using one of the many shells that support it (e.g. it is available in `bash` but not in `dash`). So for instance `column -s $'\n'` would be valid (to specify a <newline> as column separator) if run by one of those shells.

As a side-note, it's not clear to me what you'd expect from `column`. Even if it did support NUL as separator, it would just turn each line of that input into a whole column on output. Perhaps you'd wanted to also use `-t` so as to columnize the single fields for each line?

> Optional/ bonus question 2: Some data in these columns will be file paths and I wanted to use \0 as a best practice. Do you a have better practice to recommand for storing "random strings" in file without having to escape potential conflictual field separator character they may contain?

The only one I know of is by prefixing each single field with its length, expressed as text or binary as you see fit. But then surely you could not pipe them into `column`.

Also, if your concern is file paths then you should consider *not* using the `\n` either as a "structure" separator, because that is a perfectly valid character for filenames.

Just as a proof-of-concept, based on your example but using NUL as structure/record separator and length-specified fields: *(I also fiddled a bit with your example strings to involve multibyte characters)*

```c
echo -e 'line1\nline2 ò' \ | LC_ALL=C awk '
    BEGIN {
        ORS="\0"
# here we just move arguments away from ARGV
# so that awk reads input from stdin
        for (i in ARGV) {
            c[i]=ARGV[i]
            delete ARGV[i]
        }
    }
    {
# first field is the line read
        printf "%4.4d%s", length, $0
# then a field for each argument
        for(i=1; i<length(c); i++)
            printf "%4.4d%s", length(c[i]), c[i]
        printf "%s", ORS
    }
' "€ column A" $'colu\nmnB' "column C"
```

Use *arguments* to `awk` to pass as many arbitrary column strings as you wish.

Then, a hypothetical counterpart script in `awk` (actually has to be `gawk` or `mawk` to handle `RS="\0"`):

```c
LC_ALL=C awk '
    BEGIN { RS="\0" }
    {
        nf=0; while(length) {
            field_length = substr($0, 1, 4)
            printf "field %d: \"%s\""ORS, ++nf, substr($0, 5, field_length)
            $0 = substr($0, 5+field_length)
        }
        printf "%s", ORS
    }
'
```

Note that it is important to specify the *same* locale for both scripts to match the character size. Specifying `LC_ALL=C` for both is fine.

Comment: Oh wow, amazing answer, thanks for this!

Answer (score -2):

Your columns didn't even reach your awk command. Everything past the first zero was lost even before the echo command. You can't store a binary zero in a variable.

```
var=$'zzz\x00zzz'
echo "${#var}"
3
var=$'zzz\xFFzzz'
echo "${#var}"
7
```

You could use `tr` to change all the zeros to any other delimiter of your choice, before you even begin doing what you plan on doing.

Or you could change your shell to `zsh`.

Comment: zsh can store null bytes in its variables, so one solution is to change the shell

Comment: Hmm... I don't see where shell variables are involved here (just pipes); isn't what you're demonstrating here the limited escape handling of `echo`? In bash for example `printf 'zzz\x00zzz' | hexdump -C` appears to preserve the null byte

Comment: @Pourko OK point conceded - but the OP is not using `$'string'` to insert the null character, they're using awk. Are you suggesting that `FS="\0"`(for example, `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\0"; print "foo","bar"}' | hexdump -C`)  is not outputing null-separated fields?

Comment: The OP is showing using `echo` to pipe stuff to awk. That won't work nohow.

Comment: The only escape sequence OP uses in `echo` is `\n` which does work manyhow, though not everyhow, especially with `-e` which OP also uses. In _GNU_ awk a variable containing \0 works, but not FreeBSD awk (at least not my rather old one).

Comment: The point is you can't echo a string with a zero in it.

Comment: @Pourko, thank you for your aswer, just before I validate it, I want to make sure I understood correctly: If my problem comes from zero byte not beeing "passed" around (var or pipe), how come `column` does break at the exact placement of these zero bytes and displays the first column correctly, as if it detected a separator there?  Is the missing byte interpreted as a different thing here?

Comment: @Pierre-Jean "displays the first column correctly"... When passing things around, the first zero signified an end to the string, and everything after it got lost. Just pick another delimiter, anything but zero, and save yourself the headaches.

Comment: @Pourko oh nice, didn't realized that! Thanks very much for the explanation!

Comment: Umm, where's the NUL byte before the `echo`? Taking the first example, `echo -e "line1\nline2"` doesn't have any NULs in it, just regular printing chars and newline. `awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\0"} {print $1"columnA",$1"columnB",$1"columnC"}'` does have the `\0` in there, and depending on awk, it might or might not do something useful. With GNU awk, the output very much contains NUL bytes, pipe through `od -c` or such to see them. OTOH, e.g. mawk or busybox awk don't seem capable of handling the NUL. Try something like `awk 'BEGIN { print "foo\0bar"; }' |od -c` without the various implementations.

Comment: @ilkkachu He did not show his code precisely, but he said that he has zeros inside those strings. We all understood what he meant.

Comment: @Pourko, where did they say that? They said _"You would get the expected following output (\0 separators won't be displayed but is separating each field):"_  and there, in the output, it's indeed true that the NULs won't display if printed on the terminal. But they don't just spin up from nowhere on the command line, you can't expect that `echo -e "line1\nline2"` actually means having embedded NULs _there_ (or that it would mean `echo -e $'line1\0line2'` or such instead). Or well, if you do expect that, then just ask about it on a comment, or downvote and close vote with "needs more clarity".